# Acrobat fill-able form not working online.

Tags: html, forms, pdf, acrobat

I have made a acrobat form and submit it to my PHP script. It is working fine when I open the PDF with adobe acrobat and submit it.
But When I put them in a web server it is not submitting the data. It seems that submit button is doing nothing. 
**What is the proper way to display acrobat pdf form in a html webpage?**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the browser using the Acrobat plug-in to display the PDF, or is it using its own PDF viewer?

Comment: I am using PDF viewer named "pdf.js". The problem is the button is not working and it is not submitting the html value. But when i open with acrobat pdf on my PC, it works fine and I receive the data by $_POST. 
@MaxWyss

Comment: It looks very much as if the PDF viewer you are using is not supporting the actions behind the submit button. Except using a viewer which does, there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: the buttons are not working properly. it is  showing a checkbox over the button? everything else is ok. Do you have any solution for that.
@MaxWyss